# Resolve (domainless) machine name from DNS alias

Tags: c#, .net, url

So I have a URI with a DNS alias, and I need to dynamically replace the alias with the actual machine. I started out with this:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder("http://server-alias/path/to/resource");
builder.Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(builder.Host).HostName;
return builder.Uri; // http://server1.mydomain.net/path/to/resource
```

However, what I need is the URI with just the machine name, `http://server1/path/to/resource`. Of course I can use this, but string manipulation seems seems a bit kludgey:

```
builder.Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(builder.Host).HostName.Split(new[] { '.' }, 2)[0];
```

Is there a better way to get just the machine name from a DNS alias, without the domain?

Comment: I'm curious, what's the motivation for this?

Comment: @200_success [MSMQ doesn't support DNS aliases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952470/cant-send-to-msmq-with-2-dns-names) (at least the way that our servers are currently configured). Currently, we're referencing the machine names in queue addresses, but it's a requirement from our infrastructure team to remove any hard references to machine names from our applications.

Comment: So your question is really about how to replace a DNS FQDN with a NETBIOS name?

Comment: @200_success That's right.

Answer (score 2):

> However, what I need is the URI with just the machine name, `http://server1/path/to/resource`. Of course I can use this, but string manipulation seems seems a bit kludgey:
>
> ```
> builder.Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(builder.Host).HostName.Split(new[] { '.' }, 2)[0];
> ```

Also this seems to be a little bit strange, I don't know another way, only a cleaner way.

```
private Uri GetUriFromAlias(String alias)
{
    UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(alias);
    IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(builder.Host);

    builder.Host = GetMachineName(entry);
    return builder.Uri;
}
private String GetMachineName(IPHostEntry entry)
{
    return entry.HostName.Split(new[] { '.' }, 2)[0];
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `var` for the `UriBuilder` definition.